# Can I group canvases in OmniGraffle?

Tags: macos, omnigraffle

I have an OmniGraffle doc that is like 30 pages / canvases long. I'd like to organize the canvases into groups rather than just a long list. For example, I'd like to have 'Menu' below, under which the *'menu-'* canvases would be grouped. This is what it looks like currently:

[image]

I'd like it to be grouped. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible to "Group Canvases" in OmniGraffle Pro 5.

You may email omnigraffle@omnigroup.com and request this as a feature, or visit http://forums.omnigroup.com/forumdisplay.php?f=4 and post this request.

Comment: thx for answer. seems right to me